# slide navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make slide navigation. Here is my code

html

```
<li>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
   <div class="subcategories">
    <a href="#">Cleaning</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

The subcategories div is hidden.

js

```
$('li a').hover(function() {
  $(this).next().slideToggle('fast', function() {

   });
});
```

This code works. The problem is that when the mouse goes out of the li a the subcategories div disappears.

What i want is that when the user point the li a the subcategories div to be shown so the user be able to click on some link of the sub navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this please **Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/QEkDa/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/qmrHm/

Please let me know if I missed anything!

Hope rest fits the cause `:)`

**code**

```
$(".subcategories").hide();
$('li a').mouseover(function() {
       $(this).next().slideToggle('fast', function() { // <== could use slideDown

    }).mouseout(function() {
        $(".subcategories").slideUp();

    });
});​​
```

Comment: This is ok but I want the subcategories to hide when the mouse is gonna out of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').hover(function(){
    $(this).children('.subcategories').slideToggle('fast', function(){});
});
```

Try this, you need to put the hover action on li, or when you mouse over the div it will hide, because you are now on the div, not on the  anymore.

With `children()` you select the action for the nodes that are class "subcategories" under that li, but you are still on li, so it won't hide

Answer (score 0):

You use a:first

```
 $('li a:first').hover(function() {
  $(this).next().slideToggle('fast', function() {
  });
});
```